# How do I do an action when I move a view to right or left? Like a slide to lock button

Tags: android, slide

This is my layout. It has two views, I move one through the another.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/time_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/slide_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/slide_to_pause_backgound"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#0000FF" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/slide_to_pause"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/slide_to_pause_backgound"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#00FFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I set in my activity class, the view to be moved:

```
slideView = ((View) findViewById(R.id.slide_to_pause));
slideView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

And this is how I move the view:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        viewLeftMargin = X - lParams.leftMargin;
        viewTopMargin = lParams.topMargin;  
        viewBottomMargin = lParams.bottomMargin;
        viewRightMargin = X - lParams.rightMargin;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.rightMargin = X - viewRightMargin;
        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - viewLeftMargin;           
        layoutParams.topMargin = viewTopMargin;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = viewBottomMargin;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);         

        break;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

I want do an action when it goes to right and another when it goes to left.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
package com.example.motionevent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private int viewLeftMargin;
    private int viewTopMargin;
    private int viewBottomMargin;
    private int viewRightMargin;
    private int lastMarginLeft;
    private int lastMarginRight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View slideView = (View) findViewById(R.id.slide_to_pause);
        slideView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) slideView
                .getLayoutParams();
        lastMarginLeft = lParams.leftMargin;
        lastMarginRight = lParams.rightMargin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                    .getLayoutParams();
            viewLeftMargin = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            viewTopMargin = lParams.topMargin;
            viewBottomMargin = lParams.bottomMargin;
            viewRightMargin = X - lParams.rightMargin;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.rightMargin = X - viewRightMargin;
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - viewLeftMargin;
            layoutParams.topMargin = viewTopMargin;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = viewBottomMargin;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            if (layoutParams.leftMargin > lastMarginLeft) {
                Log.d("ON_TOUCH", "Moving to right!");
                lastMarginLeft = layoutParams.leftMargin;
                                lastMarginRight = layoutParams.rightMargin; // Here
            } else {
                Log.d("ON_TOUCH", "Moving to left!");
                lastMarginRight = layoutParams.rightMargin;
                lastMarginLeft = layoutParams.leftMargin; // and here
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try somthing like this.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem of left and right
Now i am trying for diagnol right and diagnol left, if you know that also please post the snipper

Comment: @SagarDevanga Sorry, I don't know in this moment!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remember the X position of the first touch on the View and in the move action determine if the user is moving to left or right by checking the difference between that point and the current position(possible taking in consideration a slide left/right default distance):

```
public static final int MOVE_SIZE = 30;
public int mStartingX = -1000;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mStartingX = X;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        viewLeftMargin = X - lParams.leftMargin;
        viewTopMargin = lParams.topMargin;  
        viewBottomMargin = lParams.bottomMargin;
        viewRightMargin = X - lParams.rightMargin;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.rightMargin = X - viewRightMargin;
        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - viewLeftMargin;           
        layoutParams.topMargin = viewTopMargin;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = viewBottomMargin;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);         
        if (mStartingX != -1000 && X >= mCurrentX + MOVE_SIZE) {
            doActionRight(); 
        } else if (mStartingtX != -1000 && X < mStartingX - MOVE_SIZE) {
            doActionLeft();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mStartingX = -1000;
        break;
```